# Complex SQL result to C# in under a second

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq

I have a SQL select statement that runs in under a second and returns 50k records matching from a leaf node table to the top of the tree four tables away.

Instead of returning 1000's of tranversable object I was looking just to return the resulting Ids and then pick the objects I want to call back.

How can I get this response into C# using SQL. Here is an example of the resulting SQL response.

**Desired Result in some sort of traversable list**

```
t1id, t2id, t3id, t4id
24683, 40252, 40, 1519  
24685, 40253, 40, 1519
```

Here is a sample query that would bring that about.

**SQL**

```
SELECT t1.Id as t1id, t2.Id as t2id, t3.Id as t3id, t4.Id as t4id
 FROM [dbo].[table1] t1 
 left join [dbo].[table2] t2 on t2.t1_id = t1.Id
 left join [dbo].[table3] t3 on t3.Id = t2.t3_id
 left join [dbo].[table4] t4 on t4.Id = t3.t4_id
```

**Code**

Code examples I was working had examples such as

```
var re = Program.db.Database.SqlQuery<List<string>>(sqlQuery).ToList();
```

Comment: What has your research revealed?

Comment: Into C# as what, an array, DataTable, LINQ query?

Comment: I have tried passing in the SQl to this but could not get a clear reponse
db.Database.SqlQuery<IEnumerable<string>>(sqlQuery)

Comment: any sort of traversable datastructure would be fine.

Comment: I did research which did not help me get the answer. All of my research found simple results with SQL on know EF objects. Just doing a raw query and mapping it back was not a common scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was close.

I was using this to try and get the result which did not work

```
var re = Program.db.Database.SqlQuery<List<string>>(sqlQuery).ToList();
```

so I made a model to cover the result

```
class Temp
{
    public int? t1id { get; set; }
    public int? t2id { get; set; }
    public int? t3id { get; set; }
    public int? t4id { get; set; }        

    public Temp()
    {            
    }    
}
```

and succeeded with this

```
var re = Program.db.Database.SqlQuery<Temp>(sqlQuery).ToList();
```

Which get me 50k results in a list.